# calculating 2D rms in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, statistics

I have a Nx2 array that stores the x,y coordinates of N different points. I have to calculate the spread of the data (I'm thinking of the rms). Are there any functions in scipy that do this job? If not, what is the most efficient way to compute this?

Comment: Have you actually done a search to see whether that's implemented in python/scipy? I come up with lots of results regarding that. Is speed really that important? What's the size of N? Have you tried implementing the RMS equation straight up? Is there any code we need to base improvements on? Have you benchmarked anything and what is an acceptable performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The root mean square is the standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square#Relationship_to_the_arithmetic_mean_and_the_standard_deviation):

```
In [100]: np.random.seed(2015)

In [101]: A = np.random.random((10,2))

In [102]: A
Out[102]: 
array([[ 0.73759523,  0.51757155],
       [ 0.88418945,  0.45172399],
       [ 0.94467608,  0.82238998],
       [ 0.06360332,  0.93889193],
       [ 0.33245351,  0.62721741],
       [ 0.00321837,  0.70402271],
       [ 0.07105811,  0.05554161],
       [ 0.28901979,  0.28649662],
       [ 0.2688956 ,  0.20721542],
       [ 0.25877509,  0.63308562]])

In [147]: np.std(A - A.mean(axis=0))
Out[147]: 0.29777164364514941
```

which is equivalent to:

```
In [146]: np.sqrt(((A - A.mean(axis=0))**2).mean())
Out[146]: 0.29777164364514941
```